# Effect of particulates on the viscosity of paste that is used to transport it in extrusion printing

Tags: extrusion

I am trying to find research articles that have data on how particulates(metal powder in a paste/hydrogel affect the viscosity of the paste/hydrogel. But I have been coming up blank in my last few hours of research. Is anyone aware of any research papers that discuss this and could point me towards them please? thanks.

Comment: There may be some helpful data at http://hyrel3d.net/wiki/index.php/Research_Papers

Comment: I suspect you won't find anything unless you're after empirical measurements of a specific compound.  Gooey (that's the technical term :-) )  materials are dang hard to model mathematically.

Answer (score 2):

I found a journal article ["Experimental study of the viscosity of suspensions"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0032591014005014)
that looks like what you are looking for.  Just like most journals, it costs to access it. Also, it might be available as Open Access; but, I was not able to figure out how.